# Parsing large XML file for specific instance of a repeating element

Tags: xml, parsing, sed

I have a very large XML file that I need to extract some information from. I have been trying to do this with a `sed` script, but I've run into some problems. There are actually two versions of the same XML file, one that is formatted nicely, and one that is just one gigantic single line of XML. I'm having different problems with each.

#### Formatted File:

One of the elements I want to extract data from is called `<name>`, but there are multiple instances of this element and I only want the data if it is in one specific context. Here's what I mean:

The XML looks something like this:

```
 <object uid="1234567890-00000000">
   <name>Object Name</name>
   <country>United States</country>
   <state>Texas</state>
   <county>Travis</county>
   <timeZone>-06:00</timeZone>
   <datum uid="datum_UID">
     <name>Datum Name</name>
     <code>DUID</code>
   </datum>
 </object>
```

My end goal is to generate a two column, whitespace delimited file that contains the object `uid` in the first column and the object `name` in the second. My first thought was to `sed` for each individually and build up two temp files with the results, then combine them into one. The problem is, when I `sed` for the name element, I can't figure out how to ONLY get the object `<name>` element, and NOT the datum `<name>` elements as well.

My `sed` script for finding the object `uid` seems to be working perfectly:

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*<object uid="\([-0-9]*\)">.*/\1/p' $infile > $outfile
```

Where `$infile` is the big XML file and `$outfile` is wherever I want to save the resulting `uid`s. Here's what I have for `name`, which obviously won't work because it will match with every instance of the `<name>` tag:

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*<name>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1/p' $infile > $outfile2
```

Is there a way to do this with `sed`? Keep in mind the file is very large (over 50 million lines). I found [this blog](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/) with a multi-line search I could try, but if I'm understanding it correctly, this would concatenate all the lines into the hold buffer before doing the search, and I don't know enough about `sed` to know if that's a really really bad idea with 50mil+ lines.

#### Single-line File:

I tried using one `sed` script to do everything in one step using the single-line file, but I ended up getting only the last match as output. Here's the `sed` script I used for that:

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*<object uid="\([-0-9]*\)"><name>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1 \2/p' $infile > $outfile
```

I think I know WHY this expression doesn't work (the `.*` at the beginning and the end matches everything before/after the data I want), but I haven't been able to fix it. I've tried a few variations in the expression, but I've never gotten the result I'm looking for. Either it only prints the last result or it prints the entire line (in this case the entire file). How can I parse out each match from the single-line file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using the XML parsing tool `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //object -v @uid -nl -v name -nl test.xml  | paste - -
```

```
1234567890-00000000 Object Name
2   second
```

given this "test.xml":

```
<objects>
<object uid="1234567890-00000000">
   <name>Object Name</name>
   <country>United States</country>
   <state>Texas</state>
   <county>Travis</county>
   <timeZone>-06:00</timeZone>
   <datum uid="datum_UID">
     <name>Datum Name</name>
     <code>DUID</code>
   </datum>
 </object>
<object uid="2">
   <name>second</name>
   <datum uid="datum_UID">
     <name>not me</name>
   </datum>
 </object>
</objects>
```

Comment: This works when I create a small test file with 2 or 3 records, but when I run my larger file through it I don't get any output. The program terminates in about 1 second with no output of any kind.

Further investigation indicates that it might be a problem with the xmlns or version in the wrapper tag. When these are included, it doesn't work, but when they aren't included it does. Do these need to be omitted or somehow handled in the `xmlstarlet` command?